# VB.NET Should I use a collection for this?

Tags: vb.net, collections

I am trying to bring my old VB6 code to a modern VB.NET code.

In my VB6 code, I need to query if a key exists in a collection.

I do it like this:

```
Private Function pIndexFromKey(ByRef uCol As Collection, ByVal uText As String) As Long
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim lRet&
  lRet = uCol.Item(uText)
  pIndexFromKey = lRet
End Function
```

If pIndexFromKey returns 0, I know that the key is not contained in the collection, and I add it like this:

```
nCollection.Add(lIndex, sText)
```

I am wondering if this is "nice" approach. I think not because in .NET I am using a VisualBasic collection, and the fact that it is "VB" and not a system collection makes me suspicious.

Just for the records, this is my VB.NET code:

```
Private Function pIndexFromKey(ByRef uCol As Collection, ByVal uText As String) As Integer
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim lRet As Integer = CInt(uCol(uText))
  Return lRet
End Function
```

The code works fine, but my On Error Resume Next approach looks ugly, and I don't like having the debug window telling me about the exception each time the error is thrown (and eaten).

Does anybody have any better ideas?

Comment: Quick tip: you don't need to mark `uCol` as `ByRef` in .NET because it is a reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Generic.Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/xfhwa508.aspx)(Of String, Integer). So instead of this:

```
Private Function pIndexFromKey(ByRef uCol As Collection, ByVal uText As String) As Integer
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim lRet As Integer = CInt(uCol(uText))
  Return lRet
End Function
```

You would have this:

```
Private Function pIndexFromKey(dict As Dictionary(Of String, Integer), uText As String) As Integer
  Dim lRet As Integer
  If dict.TryGetValue(uText, lRet) Then Return lRet
  Return -1 'default value if key was not found in the dictionary
End Function
```

Comment: You could initialize lRet as -1 and return it regardless of whether `TryGetValue` indicates failure.

Comment: @StevenDotNet: If TryGetValue fails, lRet would be 0 (default value for the type), regardless of initialized value. I corrected the code for clarity.

Comment: Eh you're right. I didn't think a TryAction method would reset the variable when it indicates failure. My bad.

Comment: @StevenDotNet: no problem, I originally had the same understanding, but then decided to check with MSDN on that, and also verified in VS, to be sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the contains method to check if a key exists.

Comment: And do you like my VB-collection approach, or is there anything faster for my case?

Comment: There are better ways in .net, check out the collections available in the system.collections.generic namespace and you can use whatever is appropriate for your circumstances. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use " on errer resume next" approach.
just  Test  the collection using "contains" method.

```
Dim  Ret as integer
Ret=0
If (uCol.contains(uText)) then
  Ret= CInt(uCol(uText))
Return ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop your VB collection and use the advanced Generic List.

In your case I suspect you are using a simple List(Of String).
If so, use this replacement for your method

```
Dim k as List(Of String) = new List(Of String) 
k.Add("Test1")
k.Add("Test2")
k.Add("Test3")
k.Add("Test4")
k.Add("Test5")

' No need to use Contains, IndexOf doesn't throw exceptions if the element is not there
Dim x = k.IndexOf("Test4")
if x = -1 then 
      Console.WriteLine("Test4 is not in list")
else 
      Console.WriteLine("Test4 is at index" + x.ToString)
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Vb.Net that you can handle the error in the Try use
Example:
Try

Catch ex As Exception

End Try

I hope I understand correctly

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a more elegant approach than using a VisualBasic collection in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace the `VisualBasic.Collection` with the `ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)` for starters. Then, get rid of your custom function and just check the `Contains()` method.

```
    Dim nCollection As New ObjectModel.Collection(Of String)
    Dim sText As String = "value"

    If Not nCollection.Contains(sText) Then
        nCollection.Add(uText)
    End If

    If nCollection.Contains(sText) Then
        Dim index = nCollection.IndexOf(sText)
    End If
```

Comment: But I also need to get the index of this key, so just the collection of strings wouldn't work.